# Using a ViewAnimator over a SurfaceView causes Problems

Tags: android

I can't seem to have any luck with normal views and SurfaceViews.  I have a FrameLayout with two children, a glSurfaceView and a ViewAnimator.  The purpose is to have a background rendering with buttons on top for menus, options and such.  When I animate from the ViewAnimator they move as they should but it appears they scroll under something, as if they were being partially masked out (the masked area seems to be related to the size of the views).  If I remove the glSurfaceView it behaves correctly (even though the onDraw in the SurfaceView does nothing but a  glClear).  I was about to give up and do another approach completely but I thought I was ask if anybody has encountered this as well.

the main xml

```
<FrameLayout    android:id="@+id/FrameLayout01"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<include android:id="@+id/glrender"  layout="@layout/glview" />
<include android:id="@+id/guiscreens"  layout="@layout/viewflipper" />

</FrameLayout>
```

the gl view

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <android.opengl.GLSurfaceView 
                    android:id="@+id/glsurfaceview" 
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"/> 

</FrameLayout>
```

the view animator

```
<ViewAnimator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/flipper"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <include android:id="@+id/first"  layout="@layout/mainmenu" />
    <include android:id="@+id/second"  layout="@layout/otherscreen" />

</ViewAnimator>
```

one of the views

```
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <Button android:id="@+id/Button01"
        android:text="CLICK ME"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </Button>

</LinearLayout>
```

I read through the docs and I thought I had everything fixed up, but I guess I am missing something.  I could not find any samples in the demos that did exactly what I was trying.  I appreciate any input, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The current animation system might not work properly on top of a SurfaceView if you use translate, scale or rotate animations. This is something that will be addressed in the future.

Comment: Do we know when/if this has been fixed?

Comment: Curious if animations are supported with SurfaceViews now?

Comment: No, you should use TextureView instead.